# Numpy masking 3D array using np.where() index

Tags: python, numpy

I created an index based on several conditions

```
transition = np.where((rain>0) & (snow>0) & (graup>0) & (xlat<53.) & (xlat>49.) & (xlon<-114.) & (xlon>-127.)) #indexes the grids where there are transitions
```

with the shape of (3,259711) that looks like the following:

```
array([[  0,   0,   0, ...,  47,  47,  47], #hour
       [847, 847, 848, ..., 950, 950, 951], #lat gridpoint
       [231, 237, 231, ..., 200, 201, 198]]) #lon gridpoint
```

I have several other variables (e.g. temp) with the shape of (48, 1015, 1359) corresponding to hour, lat, lon.

Seeing as the index are my valid gridpoints, how do I mask all the variables, like temp so that it retains the (48,1015,1359) shape, but masks the values outside the index.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `mask`?  For what kind of operation?  For somethings a masked array (`np.ma`) subclass might be useful.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I have already tried using numpy.ma.masked_where(idx, temp), but I have issues with my shape

IndexError: Inconsistant shape between the condition and the input (got (3, 259711) and (48, 1015, 1359))   @hpaulj

Comment: `masked_where` wants the boolean mask of values you want hidden, not the index tuple produced by `where`.  What's the condition matrix that produced this `where` tuple?

Comment: @hpaulj Hmm, ah okay, is there a way to use the index (using np.where), so that those indices are not masked, while the rest are masked?

Answer (score 1):

```
In [90]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(6,4)
In [91]: keep = (arr % 3)==1
In [92]: keep
Out[92]: 
array([[False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
In [93]: np.where(keep)
Out[93]: 
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Simple application of the `keep` mask gives a 1d array of the desired values.  I could also index with the `where` tuple.

```
In [94]: arr[keep]
Out[94]: array([ 1,  4,  7, 10, 13, 16, 19, 22])
```

With `keep`, or rather it's boolean inverse, I can make a masked array:

```
In [95]: np.ma.masked_array(arr,mask=~keep)
Out[95]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- 1 -- --]
 [4 -- -- 7]
 [-- -- 10 --]
 [-- 13 -- --]
 [16 -- -- 19]
 [-- -- 22 --]],
             mask =
 [[ True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False]
 [ True  True False  True]
 [ True False  True  True]
 [False  True  True False]
 [ True  True False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

`np.ma.masked_where(~keep, arr)` does the same thing - just a different argument order.  It still expects the boolean mask array.

I can do the same starting with the `where` tuple:

```
In [105]: idx = np.where(keep)
In [106]: mask = np.ones_like(arr, dtype=bool)
In [107]: mask[idx] = False
In [108]: np.ma.masked_array(arr, mask=mask)
```

There may be something in the `np.ma` class that does this with one call, but it will have to do the same sort of construction.

This also works:

```
x = np.ma.masked_all_like(arr)
x[idx] = arr[idx]
```